Tried to use cig lighter in my 12 volt plug now charger won’t work
I forgot my lighter inside and remembered I grabbed the cig lighter from my old car and tried to use it in my 04 Chevy venture and of course it didn’t work but now my Bluetooth radio connector/charger won’t work anymore

Many modern cars don't have cigarette lighter ports anymore, they have auxiliary power outlets which use the same plug, but with a lower amp rating. When you put your cigarette lighter in it tried to draw too much power and probably blew the fuse.
Replace the fuse and you'll probably be good to go, you'll find the location and fuse number in your user manual.
If the fuse isn't blown or replacing it doesn't fix your problem then it's possible the heat from the lighter damaged the port or its wiring, in which case you'd have to repair or replace it.

These sockets mighn't be rated for the high temperatures of cigarette lighters, so the socket may need to be replaced

While it's possible it got hot enough to damage the port it's unlikely as the fuse probably blew before that could happen. But you're right I should edit that in @CSM.

Thank you! I’ll try that!!

@AdamHal Also, make sure to use the correct value of fuse: if it was replaced with one of a higher current rating then the wiring would not be protected from melting/fire.

What's the power draw of a cigarette lighter?

Looks like this is the location of the relevant fuse in the 2004 Venture from the manual:

A third possibility other than blowing the fuse from the load or heat damage to the socket is that the lighter might be incompatible and have shorted out the outlet. I have a vague recollection of that being possible.

There seems to be a second fuse in the Instrument Panel Fuse Block (p. 5-108).

Start by checking the two contacts in the "lighter" hole for 12 volts, using a multimeter.  Note, the car's accessory switch may have to be on for this to work, and on other cars the ignition has to be on fully.  If there's not 12~14 volts DC then the fuse has gone.
Then check inside the "lighter" hole in the dashboard with a torch/flashlight.  There's a chance you've simply dropped carbon on the contacts, and your charger isn't connecting well.
It may need nothing more than a wipe to remove dirt.
Also check inside for melting - if the plastic got too hot then it may have allowed the metal contacts to move relative to their proper location.  If this is the case, you'll need to replace the socket or modify it.
